# How to sort a query by the results of a model's method in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a model that has a "hasMany" relationship with a second model which records "votes" for the former. I then have a method which can be called upon to simply count the number of votes, as follows:

```
class Car extends Model
{
    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vote::class);
    }

    public function score()
    {
        return $this->votes->count();
    }
}
```

In my controller, I want to run a query that returns all() but sorts by score()... something along the lines of:

```
$cars = Car::all()->sortBy('score');
```

But that doesn't work obviously... I feel like I'm on the right track, but don't quite know how to make this work. Would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the collection you were getting

Comment: I haven't been able to actually return a collection yet... the format I'm using above returns an error...

Comment: can you put the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
 $cars = Car::with('votes')->get()->sortBy(function($car)
    {
        return $car->votes->count();
    });
```

Hope it help you :)

Answer (score 0):

the code should be like this :

```
$products = Shop\Product::join('shop_products_options as po', 'po.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
->orderBy('po.pinned', 'desc')
->select('products.*')       // just to avoid fetching anything from joined table
->with('options')         // if you need options data anyway
->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply.